# Why does git config --global core.filemode false not work?

Tags: git

I have never been able to successfully use `git config --global core.filemode false` to make it such that filemode changes are ignored on all my repositories, on any environment I work on.

I have windows machines, a MBP, and two 14.04 machines, and none of them respect the global `core.filemode` setting.

Every time I make filemode changes to files in a newly cloned or created repo, I must run the command locally for it to work. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `filemode` to false on Windows,

what might be happening is as follows:

- Cygwin treats all files created by Windows as rwx by default.
- Cygwin Git sees the files with executable permission.

You can see the file mode when you do a commit, it should display the permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

remove `--global` and it will work under your repo. I'm using cygwin. You need to do it for every new repo that has this problem.